# Is there something like a 'testfor' in CMD?

Tags: cmd

I was wondering if there was a command like 'testfor' where I could have a .bat file saved somewhere on my computer and when I run the .bat it says "Good morning/Afternoon/Night (name)" and where I put (name) it reads a text file and copies the name from the text file onto the cmd?
I know that all sounds confusing but I would appreciate any help I can get!

Cheers, Joshua Hotchin

Answer (score 0):

sorry, nothing like "testfor". You have to do it manually:

```
echo Stephan>name.txt

<name.txt set /p "name="
set /a hour=%time:~0,2%
set "greet=night"
if %hour% lss 18 set "greet=afternoon"
if %hour% lss 12 set "greet=morning"
if %hour% lss 5 set "greet=night"
echo Good %greet%, %name%.
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help!